# Referencing non-static variables from a static context

Tags: java

I would like to get a better understanding on how to reference objects in java. Given this code that will raise the error “error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context”:

```
public class Catalog {
    public class Student {
        public String name;        
        ...
        }
//Student

    public static void main (String[] args){
       Student s;
       s = new Student();
    }//main
```

Q1: Why does it work if class Student is defined in another file “Student.java”?

If I want to keep the Student class definition in the same file with main subroutine, the workaround found on the post “[Non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559527/non-static-variable-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context)” is:

```
public class Catalog {
public class Student {
    public String name;        
    ...  
    }

    public static void main (String[] args){
        oopExample prg;        
        prg = new oopExample();
        prg.run();    
    }//main

    Student std1;
    public void run(){

       std1 = new Student();
       std1.name = "Tobby";
    }
}//oopExample
```

Q2: Can you tell me if this is similar from the program execution point of view with case when I use the Student class definition in a separate file?

Q3: What would be the drawbacks of declaring Student as static? and simply use the following code:

```
public class Catalog {
    public static class Student {
        public String name;        
        ...
        }//Student

    public static void main (String[] args){
        Student s;
        s = new Student();
}//main
```

Thank you for your time,

Comment: Wait! The first code snippet doesn't work?

Comment: Yeah, @CKing, `Student` here is a non-static inner class of `Catalog`,  so it needs a `Catalog` instance before it can be instantiated.  There's no such instance within the static `main` method, of course.

Comment: My point exactly. You know the answer right? Why do you still ask *Q1: Why does it work if class Student is defined in another file “Student.java”?*

Comment: @DavidWallace I need to step back and apologize. I thought the comment from you was from the OP. Based on the facts presented in the question, the OP already knows the answer. I was being sarcastic with my first comment on this post.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought it was addressed to me.  Never mind.  And I don't think OP does know the answer - they simply haven't bothered to look at all the very similar questions that have been asked before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Q1**: Why does it work if class Student is defined in another file “Student.java”?

because the (only) class in a separate file is `static` implicitly.

> **Q2**: Can you tell me if this is similar from the program execution point of view with case when I use the Student class definition in a separate file?

from the program execution point of view it does not matter (as long as you don't access something in class `Catalog` from class `Student` (which you should not do anyway, unless you have a good reason...)

> **Q3**: What would be the drawbacks of declaring Student as static? and simply use the following code:

objects of the class `Student` cannot access properties of class `Catalog` which are not declares `static`.

But again: this is something you should do with care anyway.